# Joining objects without loosing texture paint and material

Tags: mesh, materials, uv, texture-baking, performance

I'm experiencing terrible performance with Blender 4.0.2 and Macbook Pro M1 16GB Ram, 1 TB SSD with 200GB of free space. Last week Blender was amazing now it crashes everytime I press Undo or even simple tasks.

I've made this model it looks good, skeleton is made with 91 bones, all labelled, weight painted etc. I have made these eyes. The Iris is texture painted, then theres a transparent material over the top as a separate mesh.

I've managed to join the two of these objects together without an issue of loosing colours or textures but when I try to join the two eyes together or apply any transform one or the other just goes white. I've tried unwrapping them again when joined and realigning the UVs but they don't look anything like the original.

[image: Eyes with texture and Iris/Cornia Mesh Joined]

All advice I have seen so far says to select both meshes, ensure that the UV Maps are the same name and press CRL+J to join them but again they loose all information and go white. If I press CMD+J same thing. If I try to join them to the Body then same thing happens. If I try to apply all transforms same thing happens. I Loose all material detail and the object goes white.

I've texture baked the materials out into individual PBR Maps and tried to reaaply them to the mesh. Same thing I join them and it looks terrible or simply nothing like the original creation what so ever.

[image]

Comment: hello could you please pack the images and share your file?